# Is it possible to get the Foreground activity using Usage Stats?

Tags: java, android

I found this method to get the foreground activity:

```
public String getRecentActivity(Context context) { //I cut out the pre API 22 part of the method

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {

        UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        UsageEvents usageEvents = mUsageStatsManager.queryEvents(time - 1000 * 30, System.currentTimeMillis() + (10 * 1000));
        UsageEvents.Event event = new UsageEvents.Event();
        while (usageEvents.hasNextEvent()) {
            usageEvents.getNextEvent(event);
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(event.getPackageName()) && event.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND) {
            return event.getPackageName();
        }
    }
    return " ";
}
```

Here's the problem: When there's a foreground service running this method returns an empty package name instead of the package name of foreground activity (i.e. `return " ";`). How can I have it return the foreground activity? Is there a way to filter out services from usageEvents?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will fix if use `queryUsageStates` instead of `quertEvent`

```
public String getRecentActivity(){
        String mpackageName = "";
        UsageStatsManager usage = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<UsageStats> stats = usage.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 30, time);
        if (stats != null) {
            SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> runningTask = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
            for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) {
                runningTask.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
            }

            if (runningTask.isEmpty()) {
                mpackageName = "";
            } else {
                mpackageName = runningTask.get(runningTask.lastKey()).getPackageName();
            }
        }
        return mpackageName;
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry I didn't make the question clear. I want the method to return the package name of the foreground activity not the package name of the foreground service. i.e. the package name of the app the user currently has open. Your method makes it so that it returns the package name of the foreground service instead of a blank like the original. Is there perhaps a way to filter out services from the SortedMap?